# Loop through array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In an Angular app, I have made a factory, where I get all my products and put them into a factory variable. From there I can get grab them, wherever I need them. So far s good.
I then want to manually loop through all the items in the products array. I have tried the following;

My factory first

```
myApp.factory('myStore', function ($http, $q, Store) {
    var products = "";

    // Bind products
    products = Store.query();

    return {
        get: function () {
            return products;
        },
        getSingle: function(id) {
        },
        set: function (data) {
            products = data;
        },
        add: function (data) {

        }
    };
});
```

In my controller i have

```
// Bind products to list
vm.products = myStore.get();
console.log(vm.products);
for (var prop in vm.products) {
    // returns just 2 objects?
    console.log(prop);
}

for (i = 0; i < vm.products.length; i++) {
    // Does not wok at all?
}

vm.products.forEach(function (child) {
    // Does not work either. Simply does nothing.
});
```

What do I need to do to iterate through my array?

The returned products are in the correct format, and the correct values.

What gives?

The resource:

```
myApp.factory('Store', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('http://api.com/api/products/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
});
```

The output from console.log(vm.products): http://screencast.com/t/Q52EJ2F7gf

Comment: Is `Store.query()` a synchronous function?

Comment: Can you please include what is output by console.log(vm.products)

Comment: First you have to have an array to iterate over. I don't think you have one, you instead likely have an unresolved promise.

Comment: Just updated the question with some more details

Comment: So by looking at your update, it looks like you are trying to deal with async code in a sync manner; a recipe for disaster. `products = Store.query()` is a promise from what I can see...

Comment: @elclanrs okay? thanks for the input, although i dont really know what to do with it :-)

Answer (score 1):

I changed the loop to

```
vm.positions.$promise.then(function(data)
```

and then it worked. So ti was a promise issues.. ofcourse.